# Convey the meaning of "any" without using words

Tags: usability, website-design, symbols

There is a design with several drop downs to select between multiple choices.

These choices work as filters on a large dataset. When you select one of them, only the records matching the selection will be displayed.

The first choice is always "all", meaning that you don't care about that particular category.

The problem is that when translated, for languages that have gender, the translation is different depending on the gender of the category, and it's difficult for the translation engine to provide an accurate translation.

So, we want to convey this meaning using a language independent symbology. Right now we have a combination of lines and a star:

[image: screenshot]

But I am not sure this design is the best one to convey the meaning.

What are some symbols that could be used for this purpose? (Any Unicode symbol can be used.)

Comment: What would be the aria label for the symbols?

Comment: The best way of solving this problem would be A/B Testing. Considering the current situation, have some remote interviews with some of your potential users. They would easily be able to help you out here, I would say. 

We here can only guess since you didn't even provide any information related to your user base and all; hence, we might not be able to provide the best solution.

Comment: Others' suggestion convey "absence of choice" is probably for the best. A symbol to convey "don't care", [ U+1F937 Person Shrugging](https://emojipedia.org/person-shrugging/) is not formal nor truly universal!

Comment: I'm confused by the mismatch between title and question body. I think there's a difference between "any" and "all"

Comment: This is universally understandable: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` (I'm kidding, don't really do that)

Comment: @dionyziz Yes, it would be universally understanble..... and yes, I won't do that

Comment: @lucidbrot In general, all and any have different meanings. But here they have the same meaning, but applied to different things. This is a filter , filtering a data set of results with the value of one of the properties. Not applying the filter can be thought as "any" value of the property, or "all" the records. (This was at least but I was thinking when I post the question)

Comment: Use words.  Why do you assume that a star would convey the meaning "all"?  Unless you're thinking that the user is familiar with the language of regular expressions, and somehow realizes that your star is really supposed to be an asterisk?

Comment: @jamesqf, the problem with using words is that if you do so, you'll need to translate each dropdown individually.  Some languages inflect the word for "all" based on the thing it's referring to, while others don't have a standalone word for "all" -- you need to say "all colors" or "all times" or "all whatever".

Comment: @Mark: So instead of asking your users to do something relatively simple, like consult a "your language" <-> "their language" dictionary, you instead send them off on the frustrating task of trying to figure out what your symbols mean.

Comment: @jamesqf Let's say that the default language is Spanish. Then, some of the dropdowns have the word "Todos" and others have the word "Todas". Now, lets translate it to french. "Tous" or "Toutes". But in some cases, an option is masculine in spanish and feminine in french . And your dictionary is not working anymore

Comment: You could expand the wording to be "All Ratings" or "All Grades" or "All Elephants", it wouldn't be confusing for the user, and the translator would get the gender right.

Comment: @James Yes, I could. But this an expensive solution, and I am exploring cheaper ones. The items in the dropdown come from a "select distinct * from *" in the SQL, I would need to add a layer that knows what is the correct label from every select, and I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: @vals: Exploring cheaper solutions is great, just make sure that it's a solution that actually WORKS for your user.  Say your default language is English (and why shouldn't it be?).  Then a quick visit through online dictionaries give Spanish "todas", French "toute/tout", Finnish "kaikki", Japanese "subete", Latin "omnis, Gaelic "ar fad", and so on for about a hundred different languages.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you're trying to convey "this criteria doesn't matter", simply leaving it blank is probably the best option.  This used to be a very common pattern in "advanced" search dialogs, until application designers collectively decided that fancy search options were not something users needed.

Comment: Not literally blank but something like "---", just so it's clear what it means.

Comment: The answer to the title is `*`, but the answer to the body of your question is definitely blank. It's a filter, and you want to *not* filter on this criterion, i.e. no filter, blank.

Comment: A single hyphen (`-`) is likely best rather than leaving it entirely blank.

Comment: The subjectivity of `clear what it means` makes this un-clear. Nothing is clear unless it's universally understood, even language doesn't go this far. The lack of anything is the most universally clear method to denote nothing or possibly everything. <-- even here you can see it is ambiguous.

Comment: careful with things like radio buttons, though, where you'll need to add a way to clear the selection once it's been made.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow, the usual way to do that is to have a checkbox that enables or disables the entire radio group.

Answer (score 25):

I think the closest thing to a universal symbol would simply be *, which is used as a wildcard character in many operating systems and applications. It might not be recognized by every end user, but it is certainly more understandable than what you have now.

There is also the option of leaving the field blank, implying no filter will be applied.

Comment: @vals I think it’s too decorated to keep the original meaning... * and ⭐️ are not the same. I didn’t even make the connection

Comment: Unless the users are programmers, I don't think they'd recognize this idiom.

Comment: An asterisk will make sense to programmers. A ⭐️ will make sense to nobody.

Comment: @Barmar or at least command-line users (a marginally bigger group probably)

Comment: @Chris H I would argue it applies to even more than command-line users or programmers. I think anyone that has done an advanced searched on nearly any platform (from the top of my head, I know I've used it for searches with Google, ADP, Atlassian products, and ADP) is familiar with the * wild card character. The relevance of this obviously depends on OP's end-user demographic, but I think it's enough of a standard to be considered a reasonable choice.

Comment: @Joe_P I'm inclined to agree, but I program and have been working on the command line since I was 8 years old.  I've also used it on GUI  local search loads. I don't think I've ever found * useful on google though - normally I'm trying to exclude irrelevant stuff

Answer (score 9):

I assume there is no universal accepted symbol for "All". So, I would either return to text or use a slider like the price sliders on e-commerce websites or have the options shown as a list with checkbox depending on how many options you have on that element but avoid using a symbol as random as - star -

Comment: Funnily enough, one of the names for the universal quantifier "∀" is ["for all"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), but there's no standard way to shorten it to just "all" so you're right that there isn't a universal accepted symbol for it.

Comment: @DavyM Not so universal, I've learned it to be ⋀ (a "big" logic-and) in school ;)

Comment: @larkey "universal quantifier" is the concept. DavyM is not saying that ∀ is the *universal symbol* for the universal quantifier ;)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the site is translated through a translation engine (which is very much prone to error) instead of properly translated and localized (see [this](https://blog.crowdin.com/2018/09/04/5-things-every-developer-should-know-about-localization/) for starters), using the wrong gender for "any (shape)" or "any (size)" is a relatively minor problem. But let's just assume so and come up with a possible solution.

Is it unreasonable to have the first option read "All options" or "Any option"? That way, for languages that do use gender, the gender of "option" would be used, regardless of the gender of the thing that you're talking about in the form. However, even languages that have genders may have a non-gendered alternative, like "cualquiera" in Spanish ("un periódico cualquiera" - whatever newspaper (masculine), "una revista cualquiera" - whatever magazine (feminine)).

Comment: Interesting the idea about "All options".  I hadn't think about it. Thanks !

Comment: The problem isn't just grammatical gender, though that's the more common one.  There are also languages that don't have standalone words such as "all" or "none" -- instead, there are affixes that are applied to the word for the thing for which you want all or none.

Comment: @Mark Couldn't you apply the affix to the word for "option"?

Answer (score 5):

You could include the min and max values like

> 1.5 - 1.8

Then all rest of the options.

Comment: I like this one the most; it not only solves the problem but if it's the default selection gives the user extra info like "this product has indices ranging from 1.5 to 1.8" at a glance

Comment: The problem here is that it can only be used if you know your search terms are orderable. If the records had a colour field which was either "red", "green" or "blue", I'm not convinced that any user would be able to intuit that "red - blue" actually meant "any colour".

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that when translated, for languages that have genre, the translation is different depending on the genre of the category, and it's difficult for the translation engine to provide an accurate translation.

**Given problem** can be solved by using variable value based on language being used by an application. Here is how [android multi language apps](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-localization-multi-language-with-examples) are developed.

If not possible

> simply leaving it blank is probably the best option

as said by @Mark

Comment: We have the later approach on the static parts of the front end, the labels for instance. The problem is that the values in the dropdown come from the back-end, and the back-end doesnt't have this posibility. We could do some aditional processing, but I would rather avoid all this if I can make it simpler. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't leave it blank and use in clear writing "Choose one" for the default option. Then, add an option (at the top of the dropdown) for "Don't use indice".

This leaves no room for ambiguity:

If the user simply encounters a blank dropdown, or "-----," they may think they *have* to select one of the options, which may not be true.

Instead, actually guide them to choose an option, and in one of the options telling them that they have the option to select "None," seems like the least ambiguous route here, and the clearest for users, since, even if it does add an extra step for them to confirm, it avoids confusion.

Comment: I think that "Choose one" has the implication that a choice must or should be made, which is not the case here. Being required to choose that you don't want a choice is, I think, poor UX.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with some other comments here that something like `---` only indicates that nothing has been selected, but doesn't indicate if something **must** be selected. Likewise, an asterisk `*` could be mistaken to indicate that the field is required.

I only have two quick ideas, neither of which is perfect:

1. Use the infinity symbol `∞` to indicate "all", but someone could easily think that means "use the highest value possible" rather than "use **all** values".
2. If the values are for a range and are in order, perhaps list the first and last with an em dash separating them, to indicate the full range: `1.5 — 1.8`

It's perhaps also seeing if it would be feasible to expand your API to allow a string to be provided for this value so that a properly-gendered word could be provided. I have no idea if this is practical for your application. (And in any case, you would probably still want to fall back on a generic solution in case such a string did not get provided.)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps an empty set would work, like...

```
{?}
{1.5}
{1.52}
```

or

```
[ ]
[1.5]
[1.52]
```

or

```
[x]
[1.5]
[1.52]
```

Comment: The empty set will only work if the users are mathematicians.  Otherwise, those brackets are just visual noise.

Answer (score -2):

mathematicians use ∀ to mean "for all"
You could also use ∅ (empty) implying "no filter applied)

Comment: Unless the users of this application are mathematicians, ∀ is a meaningless symbol, while ∅ risks being mistaken for the letter Ø.

Comment: As Mark says, I believe this is out of the average audience. Thanks any way

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have to be particularly formal, you could use some variant of:

**¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

This one is supposed to be a shrug but doesn't render well in my browser at least:

Answer (score -3):

*.*

But you have to be old to understand that one...

Comment: More explanation required for those of us that are not that old (or pretend not to be) :p

Comment: That only matches options with a `.` in them.  If there's a 2 further down the list, it won't match.

Comment: I had think about this posibility too, but as you say I don't think that the average user will get it. (they do get the floppy disk as save, but this is another story)

Comment: Star dot Star was the way to wildcard all files in a directory using DOS.   Straight use of Star might work, but it depends on the GUI Generation understanding wildcards.  Which depends on whether the target users for this are used to Command Line Interfaces.  Question 1 is always 'who are the users'?

Comment: @PhillipW, these days, users with a command-line mindset are more likely to be Linux users, where `*.*` does *not* match everything.

Comment: Ta. Yes now is not then.  How about CTRL+A, since that's a standard Windows shortcut for "select all" ?

Answer (score -3):

The audience for this question is pretty high-brow. In my experience, "Concept" does not inform "assumption". Hence, the UI does need to be specifically worded. Murphys' Law

"Use words. Why do you assume that a star would convey the meaning "all"?"

Comment: Can you provide some suggestions of the wording for completeness of the answer?